# Insert query from a select using tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making this script where I need to insert values from a MySQL database to another. Thing is I've run into this lines of code:

```
with cursor2(SSDictCursor) as cur:
cur.connection
for i in filas:
    query = cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES (i['valueA'],i['valueB'])')

    cur.connection2.commit()
```

Thing is this gives an error where I can't get the values like this, I know, but I've tried anything and I'm kinda desperate with this.

Another thing I've tried is

```
    with cursor2(SSDictCursor) as cur:
cur.connection
for i in filas:
    insert = i['valueA'],\
             i['valueB']

    query = cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES '
                       (f'({insert})')

    cur.connection2.commit()
```

And this doesn't seem to work either and
I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: Hey, the syntax is definitely wrong. So for an f-string:-
cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO table (value1, value2) VALUES ({i["valueA"]},{i["valueB"])}')
Need braces around the pythonic part and use double quotes within the quote

Comment: Thank you so much for answering, I still don't understand the difference between simple brackets and double brackets and their functionality. Anyways it helped a lot.
Now I'm getting a syntax error coming from MySQL lol. Guess I'll dig in that way.
Again thank you sou much for the help. Cheers